# modify regex for leading space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex in a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8G463/) that works great (alphanumeric with some punctuation) but I want to also remove the leading space, while still allow spaces elsewhere. What do I need to change?

```
var TheCleanString = TheInput.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\s\(\)\.\-]+/g, '');
```

Comment: What about using `replace` method one more time? `TheInput.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\s\(\)\.\-]+/g, '').replace(/^\s+/, '');`

Comment: It sounds like you are just looking for a `.trim()` function.

Comment: no, I'm not looking for the .trim() function, just pure regex.

Comment: This part ` \\s` in your negative class is a space, a escape char, and an 's'. The 's' is coverd in NOT a-z. The regex leaves spaces and escape characters. Leaving escape characters without removing what they escape can be very problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with single RegExp, here is my proposal:

```
TheInput.replace(/(^\s+|[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\s\(\)\.\-]+)/g, '');
```

**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgDZk/)**

But if I were you I would use multiple `replace` methods because it's easier to understand the code:

```
TheInput.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\s\(\)\.\-]+/g, '').replace(/^\s+/, '');
```

Comment: Ok, thanks; this is what I'm looking for because I want to use the same regex on the client and the server for input validation. Why do you recommend multiple .replace() calls?

Comment: @frenchie you're welcome:) I would use multiple `replace` methods because in my opinion it's more clear to understand

Answer (score 1):

Search for ^[ \t]+ and replace with nothing to delete leading whitespace (spaces and tabs)

Ripped off of: http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

-

Another option is using a trim()

Answer (score 0):

You should use `^` to mark the begin of the string.

You could use something like this. Replacing it with $1 will give you the string without leading spaces.

```
^[ ]+(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find:

```
 #  /(?:^\s+|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s().-]+)/

 (?: ^ \s+ | [^a-zA-Z0-9\s().-]+ )
```

Replace:
     ''